# How Nginx Sends reuests?

Tags: nginx, web-server

i am new to nginx and currently i am using nginx as a reverse proxy , we are using nginx to route the request to other urls , For example i have below code ,

```
location /test/rome/ {

   
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        #remove this line if you application does not depend
        proxy_set_header X-HttpRouter-REMOTEADDR  $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://test.com/1234/test2/;
```

So in the above config i am saying any requests comes to /test/rome should redirect the request to the proxy pas url ? Is that mean do i need to open the FW connectivity from nginx servers to the server mentioned in proxy_pas ?

Comment: This `location` block does not match the URI `/test/rome` The trailing `/` is significant. If you want to handle `/test/rome` with `test.com`, you need to remove the trailing `/` from the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this setup proxies requests with prefix `/test/rome` to the URL specified in `proxy_pass`.

And yes, nginx on the server needs to be able to open TCP connection to the destination server.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly i needed